# Compatible maps

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

**Definition** Let $M$ be a subset of a metric space $X$ and $T, I :M\to M$ be $M$-invariant maps. Then the pair $(T,I)$ is called compatible if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}d(ITx_n, TIx_n)=0$$
whenever ${x_n}$ is a sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}Ix_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}Tx_n=t$ for some $t\in M$.

**Example** Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric and $M=[0,1]$. Let $T, I :M\to M$ be defined by
$$ T(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} & \text{if  $0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2} $} \\
\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{4} & \text{ if $\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 1$ }
\end{cases}$$
and 
$$ I(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} & \text{if  $0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2} $} \\
1-x & \text{ if $\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 1$ }
\end{cases}$$
**Question** Are $I$ and $T$ compatible?

Comment: Yes, I have tried and found that if the sequence $\{x_n\}$ lies in $[0,1/2]$ or $[1/2,1]$ then $I$ and $T$ satisfy the compatiblity but I am not sure when some term of sequence comes from  $[0,1/2]$ and some comes from $[1/2,1]$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $I$ and $T$ are continuous. If $(x_n)\subseteq [0,1]$ satisfies $\lim Ix_n=\lim Tx_n=t$ for some $t$, then $t$ lies in the closure of both $I(M)=[0,1/2]$ and $T(M)=[1/2,1]$, so $t=1/2$. Using the continuity of $T$ and $I$, we obtain
$$\lim TIx_n=T(1/2)=1/2=I(1/2)=\lim ITx_n,$$
and this implies that $T$ and $I$ are compatible.